# Escaping single quote

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div like this:

```
<div class='myclass'></div>
```

Sometimes i need to make these div dynamically and add another class to it. I do it like this

```
if(condition1)
  appendClass = 'xyz'
if(condition2)
  appendClass = 'abc'
if(condition3)
  appendClass = 'usb'

$('main').append("<div class = myclass "+ appendClass +"/>")
```

but when i check this div with firebug i get this

```
 <div class="myclass" xyz=""/>
```

which should have been

```
 <div class="myclass xyz"/>
```

I tries using `append.replace(/"/g, '')` but same result. 
Please help!!

Comment: You don't automatically get the quotes around the class name if you don't specify them like `"<div class='myclass " + appendClass + "'/>"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do something like this

```
$("<div>").addClass("myclass " + appendClass).appendTo($(".main"))
```

Comment: But then this would add the class to all pre existing div also?

Comment: No @SankalpMishra - only the one that is being created.  It's not `$("div")` - it's `$("<div>")`

Comment: @Brian - there's no space between the 2 class names, and `main` is a class ;)

Comment: @Brian Ok..but if i have to prepend it then?

Comment: @Archer Fixed. I like the attention to detail :-). You can use prependTo http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/

Answer (score 7):

```
$('main').append("<div class =' myclass "+ appendClass +"' />")
```

but my personal preference is:

```
$('main').append('<div class="myclass ' + appendClass + '"/>');
```

Comment: maybe do you need to fix the selector? $('#main') instead of $('main')?

Comment: Take a look at Brian's answer too. It's better structured code.

Answer (score 1):

You can mix single and double quotes to quote things in strings, like this...

```
$('.main').append("<div class='myclass " + appendClass + "' />")
```

Comment: What is `main`?  Is it a div or class - the selector doesn't specify and it must :)

Comment: It is a class and i have used it as .main

Comment: So when you added my suggestion, you used `.main`?

Comment: If you remove the class and just append a div, does it work then?

Answer (score -1):

try This

```
$( ".myclass").addClass(appendClass);
```

Comment: He's creating the div on-the-fly.  There is no `.myclass` on the page.

Comment: That will add appendClass to elements that have a class myclass not append a new element with myclass + appendClass